# Не срабатывает onclick на тачскрине некоторых мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, jquery, адаптивная-верстка, мобильная-разработка, touch-event

Здравствуйте, для реализации кнопки с выпадающим меню для мобильных устройств написал простую функцию:

```
$('.mobile-menu-button').on('click', function(){    
        $(this).toggleClass('on');// не имеет отношение к проблеме.
        $('.main-menu').slideToggle('fast');        
    });
```

Так вот, на некоторых смартфонах работает все отлично (насколько я понял, на более новых моделях, но это не 100% факт), на некоторых - **событие  вообще не срабатывает**( (смартфоны Dexp, huawei и даже nokia) - меню не открывается.

П. С. У кнопки  .mobile-menu-button нет css-псевдокласса :hover, только "прикручен" вышеуказанный обработчик.

Скрин: как должно быть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Браузеры одинаковые используются на данных смартфонах при тестах? Пробовали играться с версиями jquery?

Comment: @Aaron, не знаю, у меня нет столько смартфонов. Товарищи звонят и говорят: так и так, не работает. Кстати, используются стандартные функции jquery, которые по идее должны работать во всех браузерах...

Comment: если используется свежая версия jquery, то попробуйте более старые ветки. Да и вообще, зачем вешать на js задачу, которую можно сделать при помощи стилей

Comment: @Aaron, возможно, причина в относительно новом методе .on()?

Comment: может, попробуйте реализовать задачу другим способом просто.

Comment: @Aaron, "Да и вообще, зачем вешать на js задачу, которую можно сделать при помощи стилей". Вы имеете в виду правило :nover? Я бы хотел сделать плавное открытие меню, плюс у меня еще и подменю должны открываться соответствующим образом...

Comment: Знаю такую проблему c ios, решается `cursor: pointer` для элементов, без него событие клик не вешается.

Comment: Прикрепите так же html код

Answer (score 2):

Можешь попробовать использовать аналогичные touch события:

- ontouchstart - аналогичен onmousedown
- ontouchend - аналогичен onmouseup (подходит больше)

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего, проблема заключается в том, что событие onclick не обрабатывается на touchscreen.

Я ответ нашёл на [Хабре](https://qna.habr.com/q/891097)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)